# Why doesn't border of form input turn dark red?

Tags: html, css

As you can see I'm trying to make the input's border to become dark red as a user starts using it. For some reason, this code doesn't work.

**What can be the problem? And how to fix that?**

```css
input:focus {
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="user_input">
```

Comment: it does work as intended !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in several browsers there is already a style when an input is focused. Your darkred boder does work, however what you are seeing is the default style, to remove it use the following `outline:none;` [Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)

```html
<style>
input:focus {
    border: 3px solid darkred;
    outline: none;
}
</style>

<input type="text" name="user_input">
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't "darkred" is a recognizable color name. Try using the HEX code or RGB value  of dark red.

ie.

```css
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #BD0101;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend researching before posting an answer, as `darkred` is explicitly in W3’s [spec](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords). -1

Comment: ``darkred`` is equivalent to hex color code #8B0000 and is a valid color.